# DevEnv to build BizTalk Visual Studio 2013 solution from command line

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, biztalk, devenv

I'm running the following:

```
D:\GitRecompile>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" MyFolder\MyApp.sln /build "Debug"
```

It gives no error, no results, nothing.  Almost like I just hit enter from the command line.

I'm trying to do a batch rebuild of several BizTalk Projects from the command line to make sure all code was checked-in corretly.

I also tried:

```
D:\GitRecompile>c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild MyFolder\MyApp.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
```

It ran, but got a lot of errors, such as xxx.xsd.cs could not be found. BizTalk creates the .cs from the .xsd at build time; so it seems like the build should have created those files.

Comment: Maybe try running msbuild from the same folder as the .sln.  Also, double check the Build Config is Debug, for upgrades it can be different.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot when I circle back to this project.